# Get the value of CharField as integer

Tags: django, django-models

I got a model looking like below.

I want to get the value of the CharField as 23 not '23' as an example.
How can I best approach this without hackie solutions?

Use case: I need the price per unit to be timed with the quantity amounts and then it should add the chosen amount of VAT (Which is percentages of the total value of unit price and unit quantity) on top of it

```
class InvoiceItem(models.Model):
    VAT_AMOUNT = (
        ('0', '0%'),
        ('5', '5%'),
        ('8', '8%'),
        ('23', '23%')

    vat_rule = models.CharField(choices=VAT_AMOUNT, default=23)
    unit_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=2)
    quantity = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=0, default=1)

    def __str__(self):
      return self.service

    def get_total_unit_price(self):
      item_total = self.unit_price * self.quantity * (1 + self.vat_rule / 100)
      total = round(item_total, 2)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do this by taking integer field also like

```
VAT_AMOUNT = (
        (0, '0%'),
        (5, '5%'),
        (8, '8%'),
        (23, '23%')
        )
```

and define field:

```
vat_rule = models.IntegerField(choices=VAT_AMOUNT, default=23)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make it `IntegerField` or if you really need to keep it as `CharField` make it with setter and getter

```py
_vat_rule = models.CharField(choices=VAT_AMOUNT, default=23)

@property
def vat_rule(self):
    try:
        return int(self._vat_rule)
    except:
        return 0

@vat_rule.setter
def vat_rule(self, value):
    self._vat_rule = value
```